# Sencha touch button ui forward type

Tags: sencha-touch-2.2

I have a toolbar with two buttons to navigate a carousel. I have back and forward as the button ui values. In the default sencha theme the buttons look right with back and forward L&F. But when i change the theme to cupertino. The forward button does not get the button ui. Attaching the screenshot below

[image: This is how it looks in sencha theme][image: The cupertino theme displays like this, missing the right >]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ios does not have a forward button type. So I had to modify the css to provide that forward button type.

```
.x-button.x-button-forward {
  border : 0px;


  &:after {
    content: '!';
    font-family: 'iOS7';
    color: $ios7-blue;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: transparent;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }


  .x-button-label {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 2px;
  }
}
```

Please take a look at this link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?279139-Forward-button-UI-in-Cupertino-theme&p=1020204&viewfull=1#post1020204